# changing property of a link

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following `html` text.

```
<ol class="otherstufflinks">
    <li> 
        <a href="./pythonNotes/index.html">Python notes</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a href="./figure.html">Cool figure made using</a> 
        <a href="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/" class="nestedlink">d3.js library.</a>
    </li>             
</ol>
```

The relevant parts in my `css` file are:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    color: steelblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: rgb(210,135,60);
}

.otherstufflinks > li,
.otherstufflinks a:link, .otherstufflinks a:visited 
{
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgb(75,75,75);
}

.otherstufflinks a:hover  {
    color: rgb(210,135,60)
}
```

I want to choose a different color, say red, for the link with the class `nestedlink`. Would appreciate if someone can tell me how to do that? I tried the following but none of them work.

First try:

```
.nestedlink a:link, .nestedlink a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

Second try:

```
.otherstufflinks .nestedlink a:link, .otherstufflinks .nestedlink a:visited {
        color: red;
   }
```

I don't see where I am going wrong. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.nestedink:link, a.nestedlink:visited {
color: red;
}
```

I believe with the a and only using .nestedlink, the default a:link property would override the .nestedlink.

Comment: Thanks Jake and Kasapo. But then, why does it work in case of `.otherstufflinks a:link`. BTW your answer worked great. Thanks. SO says I have to wait 7 minutes before I can accept it.

Comment: .otherstufflinks a:link means the <a> anchor resides within a parent element with class 'otherstufflinks'.  In your example, you set the <a> class to nestedlink.

Comment: Because "a:link" is a descendant of the div with the class "otherstufflinks" this works. However, a.nestedLink:link is the same in this case.

Comment: btw, spaces between classes/ids/psuedoclasses mean "descendant of," whereas ">" means direct descendant (child) and "+" means sibling. If you omit the spaces like ".otherstufflinks.nestedLink" your style wouldn't apply to anything because that means "elements with a class of otherstufflinks AND nestedLink". If you want to learn more, look into "CSS Selectors" http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: one more, fwiw:

".otherstufflinks .nestedLink" is equivalent to "ol.otherstufflinks a.nestedLink". In this specific example, you could even do "ol .nestedLink" but that's probably not what you would want unless this was the only ordered list on the page, or if you had other ols with nestedLinks that you wanted formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Just try

```
a.nestedlink:visited, a.nestedlink:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

surely?

Comment: This is not specific enough to override the other selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Your css is bad, try:

```
a.nestedlink { color: red; }
```

This means "apply to element of type 'a' (anchor) with class nestedLink". What you had means "apply this to any anchor that is a descendant of an element with a class nestedLink"

Comment: No. I did not copy and paste. I typed out `nestedlink` correctly. It still did not work.

Comment: Ah yeah, i was typing in camel caps because i thought that's what i read -- my bad. "nestedlink" and "nestedLink" are different classes to the DOM, so yeah, gotta match the casing.